# how can i put in all body background color css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following problem when trying to place in the body the great color does not take me in the body all the style only captures me to a certain size, if the window has scrooll as the image comes out two shades of colors, I would like to get the whole background of the color in the body. it's possible? This is my code used.

[Capture Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iymwS.png)

lang-css

```css
  
body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-155deg, #ea4853, rgba(125, 44, 160, 0.9));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-content">
    <div class="flex-column" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h1>Historial </h1>
                        <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: -90px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 80px;">
                                    <div style="display: block;">
                                        <canvas baseChart width="400" height="300" [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels" [options]="lineChartOptions" [colors]="lineChartColors" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 table-log">
                                    <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels">{{label}}</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
                                            <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index">{{d && d.data[j]}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please convert your code to CSS and HTML so that the snippet can be run.

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat;` is a start

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bnm6d4k3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `height: 100%;` to `height: 100vh;`

However this wont solve your issue when you start scrolling

I Personally would do it like so:

```css
body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-155deg, #ea4853, rgba(125, 44, 160, 0.9));
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<h1> HI!</h1>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
Oooooh Yeaaa!
```

Here are the fundemantal amendments.

```
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
```

What it does is set your height of the body to `100vh`. This will mean what ever the **View Height** of the screen is it will equal the body size.

Then `background-attachment: fixed;` Makes it so the background acts like an image or a div that's position fixed. It means the background will stay in that position on scroll.

> Why did i use a bunch of `<br />`

I could have used `min-height: 400vh;` to make scroll. However this still wouldn't have fixed his issue. He would need to still have 100vh. to fix the issue.

**HOWEVER**

You could add the following to body css `background-size: 100vw 100vh;` / `background-size: 100% 100%;` / `background-size: cover;`which would mean `min-height: 400vh;` could be added

Thus a tidier verison:

```css
body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-155deg, #ea4853, rgba(125, 44, 160, 0.9)) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Using `Background-size:` Is better as it has much more support browser wise over `vh` > See [Can I Use (Background-size)](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) | [Can I Use (Vh)](https://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

**Some further Reading:**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />... Really? o.O

Comment: To solve the "scrolling problem", there is something called `min-height`.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac I could have done it another way but ... ye. 
stender Is correct was just to make it scroll.

Comment: Why not `<div>`(within body)  with height `110vh`? Using `<br />` to achieve space rings all kinds of alarms and red flags. Even if you know what you are doing and just using it simply to save time, it can still confuse someone less experienced and give them the idea that it is a correct way of doing things. That's why I would have avoided it.

Comment: If you are using `background-size`, there is `cover` available. See my answer.

Comment: @Vision If either answer helped and fixed your issue don't forget to tick it

Answer (score 0):

Codepen to see the result:
https://codepen.io/nemanjaglumac/pen/eQQMda

And the code itself:

```
<body>
  <div>Just a spacer</div>
</body>

$colorPrimary: hsla(282, 57%, 40%, 0.9);
$colorSecundary: hsla(356, 79%, 60%, 1);

body {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-155deg, $colorSecundary, $colorPrimary) no-repeat ;
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  height: 110vh;
}
```

Further reading: 
[MDN: CSS Background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)